# why does this code stop without raising error?

Tags: python

I want to collect some data which is more than two in a list.
For this, I wrote code like the one below.

```
A= ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b']
for ab in A:
    ab_list = list()
    for _ in range(A.count(ab)):
        Ab_list.append(A.pop(A.index(ab)))
        # other code ~
```

When I checked the code, it didn't work at `'c'`, `'d'`.
It just stops when all `'b'` in list A are removed.
For me, it's okay because `'c'`, `'d'` is just one, but I want to know the reason it stops at `'c'` and `'d'`.

Please help newbie
thanks expert

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, you are iterating over `A` while modifying it, which is the cause of your error.

Comment: is it typo `Ab_list` or is another list

Comment: I guess you want `ab_list = list(filter(lambda x: A.count(x) > 1, set(A)))`. You can also use list comprehension `ab_list = [i for i in set(A) if A.count(i) > 1]`.

Comment: @Olvin using `count` repeatedly is not really efficient, better use a `Counter` once (assuming this is what OP wants) ;)

Comment: @mozway, it depends actually. I've done benchmark once answering quite similar question and up to some fairly large amount of items N calls of `list.count()` performed better.

Comment: @mozway, [benchmark](https://tio.run/##jdLNaoQwEADge55i8KKCCKseylIL0sdYSogxoUNNIjHC7tPb@LtLcenmEMlk5tNM7G7u2@j8rbPjKK1RwE3bCu7Q6B5QdcY6@DSDdsISUkEJl5CFCSxTvU/zkk9Ts8S@CGmEBHmKWHwm4IcVbrAaWuxdJLH1YNQyVTcMrmdgKZ9eEl1j@IBTAr1wvjCOVyX7q1wQpLGAgHrNBZS7grOyfUL@rDgBPtWvx/NZKTqh@mi2@CNR7MSTQmV6R7lRyuhozZzG7LxDdo9Mo7aC/eyRG4q2ASTEJ1OqmRKUQllCSKliqCkNl@r1MhwqgW6OdBb9YQPf4yoOknUnXR73sG/P0JXBfLkbuWHSt7oKfJsfueyYy17gsgMuP@byF7j8gCsOueWvmvb@RYsFHcdf).

Comment: For a start, it helps extracting a [mcve] and then stepping through the code with a debugger. What is surely brittle here is that you modify the sequence you iterate over, avoid that. Use a new list/dict/string/array and transfer elements selectively instead. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @OlvinRoght `A = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b'] * 100` then `[i for i in set(A) if A.count(i) > 1]` vs `c = Counter(A) ; [x for x, i in c.items() if i>1]`, the `Counter` is faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 A = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b']

 ab_list = [character for character in set(A) if A.count(character) > 0] 
 print(ab_list)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Your problem in this line

```
for _ in range(A.count(ab)):
```

You receive count of current character, for example 2, and after make loop by this value. So loop check only 2-3 first element is array.

**But if you want just count elements in array, you can use numpy**

```
A = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b']
# count element in A array
B = np.unique(A, return_counts=True)
```

Results:

```
(array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='<U1'), array([3, 3, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Beware that `numpy` is **not** a general-purpose drop-in replacement for `list`. It's a specialized numeric, homogeneous array.

Comment: What's the purpose of `ab`? Why is the print outside of the loop? Also, calling count for each character isn't very optimized since it counts all other characters every time